# ActiveAdmin sortable error in production

Tags: postgresql, activeadmin, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to sort the trainings by their owner, whose name is included in my profile model.
A Training belongs to a Profile.

I have this in my trainings.rb:

```
column "Owner", :sortable => :profile_name do |training|
     if training.profile.nil?
        "No associated profile"
     else
        training.profile.name
     end
end
```

I get this error in production:

```
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms

ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "profile_name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "trainings".* FROM "trainings"  ORDER BY "profile_na...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "trainings".* FROM "trainings"  ORDER BY "profile_name" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
column "Owner", :sortable => 'profile.name' do |training|
```

Let me know if that works for you!